# Remove enum from array of enums regardless of its argument

Tags: swift, enums

I have an enum `BulletinOptions`:

```
enum BulletinOption {
    case notificationPermissions
    case enableNotifications(eventId: String)
    case join(hostName: String, eventId: String)
    case share(type: SocialBulletinItem.BulletinType.Social, event: EventJSONModel, view: UIView)
    case completedShare(type: SocialBulletinPageItem.SocialButtonType)
}
```

I have an array of these enums like this:

```
let array = [
    .join(hostName: hostName, eventId: event.id),
    .notificationPermissions,
    .enableNotifications(eventId: event.id),
    .share(type: .queue(position: 0, hostName: ""), event: event, view: view)
]
```

I want to create a function that can remove a specific enum from this array. I have this code:

```
func remove(
    item: BulletinOption,
    from options: [BulletinOption]) -> [BulletinOption] {
    var options = options

    if let index = options.firstIndex(where: {
        if case item = $0 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }) {
        options.remove(at: index)
    }

    return options
}
```

What I want to do is this:

```
let options = remove(item: .enableNotifications, from: options)
```

However, this gives me two errors. The `remove` function says:

> Expression pattern of type 'BulletinOption' cannot match values of type 'BulletinOption'

for the line:

```
if case item = $0
```

The second error is when calling that function:

> Member 'enableNotifications' expects argument of type '(eventId: String)'

I just want to delete that enum regardless of its argument. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently impossible.

What you are trying to do is essentially passing an *enumeration case pattern* as an argument to a method, so that that method can match each value in the array against that pattern. However, the [swift guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID424) says that:

> An enumeration case pattern matches a case of an existing enumeration type. Enumeration case patterns appear in `switch` statement case labels and in the `case` conditions of `if`, `while`, `guard`, and `for-in` statements.

This means that enumeration case patterns are not allowed as arguments to functions. :(

So the best you can do is this:

```
array.filter {
    if case .enableNotifications = $0 { return false } else { return true }
}
```